# How to set the size attribute of a Material UI Select component with multiple options?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, formik-material-ui

I'm trying to set what would be the `size` attribute on a native HTML select element. This dictates how many options to show (i.e. the vertical height) in the multi-select. I cannot see a prop for this [in the docs](https://material-ui.com/components/selects).

```
<Field
  component={Select}
  disabled={props.disabled}
  name={props.name}
  multiple
  native
  size={props.size || 4}
>
  {props.children}
</Field>
```

The `size` attribute is ineffective here and appears to default to four options but I'd like more.

The `Field` component in the example code is from [formik](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik) and `Select` is from [formik-material-ui](https://stackworx.github.io/formik-material-ui).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `size` via `inputProps`:

```
<Field component={Select} multiple native inputProps={{ size: 6 }} ...>
  {options}
</Field>
```